# elementary abelian groups and finite fields

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, finite-fields

in group theory, an elementary abelian group is a finite abelian group, where every nontrivial element has order $p$, where $p$ is a prime; it is a particular kind of $p$-group. now suppose that we have a finite field $GF(p^n)$ and we want to consider it as a vector space over $GF(p)$. Can we claim that $GF(p^n)$ is an elementary abelian group? I have already read the answer of "Amitesh Datta". [Finite fields as vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42546/finite-fields-as-vector-spaces)

Comment: Yes, the underlying abelian group of any finite field is elementary abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elementary abelian group $\;G\;$ is one for which $\;pg=0\;$ for some prime $\;p\;$ and for all $\;g\in G\;$, i.e. any non-trivial element has (additive, in my writing) order equal to $\;p\;$

Now ask yourself whether it is true that $\;pa=0\;\;\forall\,a\in GF(p^n)\;$ ...

Comment: so for elements of GF(4) which are 0,1,2,3, the order of 3 is not equal to 2. right?

Comment: Those are **not** the elements of $\;GF(4)\;$ , @user118746 ...!I'm afraid you're confussing the field with 4 elements and the **non-field ring** $\;\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z=:\Bbb Z_4\;$ with four elements.

Comment: GF(p) is called the prime field of order p , and is the field of residue classes modulo , where the  elements are denoted 0, 1, ...,p-1 . ? The finite field GF(2) consists of elements 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes to both your questions. **Only** when $\;n=1\;$ we have that equality $\;GF(p)=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$, @user118746

Comment: @user118746: Look up [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172980/11619) for the arithmetic of $GF(4)$. Some aspects of the arithmetic operations in $GF(8)$ and $GF(16)$ are spelled out [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619).